# delete all QSpacerItem from a layout

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qlayout

I've added a `QSpacerItem` to a layout using its `addStretch()` method.

```
layout->addStretch(1);
```

now i'd like to delete it but i didn't have any reference to it.

how can I browse all `QLayoutItem` and only delete `QSpacerItem` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would personally write this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < layout->count(); ++i) {
    QLayoutItem *layoutItem = layout->itemAt(i);
    if (layoutItem->spacerItem()) {
        layout->removeItem(layoutItem);
        // You could also use: layout->takeAt(i);
        delete layoutItem;
        --i;
    }
}
```

So, the logic would be this in a nutshell if the code does not make it clear:

- Look up all the items of the layout.
- Check if it is a spacer item.
- If it is, remove it.

Comment: Iterating backward would be strange to me. The same issue is solved by a simple --i, thanks. Delete is also added, thanks. @Ghilas BELHADJ, you may wish to integrate my bugfixes into your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should not to delete QLayoutItem if you add it to QLayout. [It's QLayout responsibility](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#addItem) to delete it children.

> Note: The ownership of item is transferred to the layout, and it's the layout's responsibility to delete it.